# A Fundamental Theorem of Algebra type Result

Tags: open-problem

Consider a polynomial $$p(t)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_it^{b_i}+a_0$$ of degree $b_n$, show that it admits at most $n+1$ nonnegative roots and at least one complex root. Assume all $b_i$ are positive and $a_i$ are real numbers.

Attempt: Using successively Rolle's Theorem we can prove that it admits at most $2^{n-1}$ nonnegative roots.

Comment: What does $[b_n]$ mean ?

Comment: The integer part of $b_n$.

Comment: Is this an exercise or a conjecture ?

Comment: Something in between.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs

Comment: Are the $a_n$ real or complex?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I'm pretty sure the OP means for the exponents $b_i$ to be positive *reals*, not necessarily integers. Does the rule of signs generalize?